# Encoding Issues with Microsoft Word Symbols [ UTF-8 To ISO-5589-1 ]

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, content-type, decoding

I have been having a hell of a time dealing with content that has been copy and pasted from Microsoft Word, and submitted to our system.

Content includes multi-byte symbols like: `“ ” ’`, which I would like to converted to `" " '`.

Since our app / database is configured for UTF-8, these multi-byte symbols are submitted and stored with no issues.  But when we syndicate our information to a third party that uses ISO-8859-1, we run into some encoding issues.

Has anyone had this issue?  Or have a possible solution?

Comment: What exactly would you like to do with all the characters that aren't expressible in iso-8859-1? Throw them away? Try to find a close match? Replace them all with a `?`?

Comment: Ideally find the single byte equivalent for the most popular instances. quotes, apostrophes, etc.  Any other instances can be ignored if they are unable to be expressed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the built in [String#force_encoding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) method will convert multi-byte symbols into representations of themselves, rather than replacements, you can't use that.

```
str = "“ ” ’"
str.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1")
#=> "\xE2\x80\x9C \xE2\x80\x9D \xE2\x80\x99"
```

You could try [String#encode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode), but that can only replace *all* invalid/undefined characters with something, not each individually.

```
str = "“ ” ’"
str.encode("ISO-8859-1", :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "")
#=> "  "

str = "“ ” ’ €"
str.encode("ISO-8859-1", :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "'")
#=> "' ' ' '"
```

Most likely, you'll need to write or find a library that maintains a relationship between unicode multi-byte characters and the ASCII characters they correspond to, and use that.